# Centos 5.5 install PearDB

Tags: linux, php, centos5, pear

Disclaimer: I use Linux for some jobs but I am *not* a Linux admin.

I have a Centos 5.4 machine which performs some server duties and doubles as a web site development machine. PHP 5.3.3 was installed from RPM with the `--without-pear` option. I now wish to use PearDB but can't figure out how to install it.

If I run `yum install php-pear-db`, it comes back with

`Error: Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (updates)`.

The only RPM I've found that looks like it might be close currently has a dead link, so I can't even try that.

What would be the best way to go about this? Is there a way to reinstall from the RPM and include pear? Can I install the dependency without breaking the current installation? Should I try to uninstall the original PHP and reinstall it from source, complete with pear?

I thought this might have been an SU question but the FAQ over there suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your easiest bet is to simply uninstall the php and php-devel packages using yum, then use yum to install php-pear-DB. It will then grab all of the other dependencies for php and php-devel.

Comment: Will yum properly uninstall packages installed from RPM?

Comment: Absolutely. `yum erase PACKAGE` will erase the package and dependencies. Be careful on what you erase, and keep a lit of what was removed so you can reinstall using `yum install PACKAGE`.

Comment: I should add that yum is the system standard RPM package manager used in RHEL/CentOS. It appears that php-pear-DB is part of the Extras repository so make sure the `[extras]` section is uncommented in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`.